# Desktop vs Mobile layout for `code`

Tags: bug, design, mobile

Looking at [Linux Output Into Table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404382/linux-output-into-table).

On a desktop display it's quite clear that there are two `code` tables. The first has one column and the second has two.

Using my mobile device (Firefox and Chrome) I see both tables as single lines of code. Initially the question didn't make sense, and it wasn't until I saw an answer referencing the supposed tables that I realised it was a display issue.

**Mobile**

[image: Mobile presentation]

**Desktop**

[image: Desktop presentation]

I appreciate that the question owner has used a multi-line backtick construct rather than four-character indentation. But this seems to be a fairly common occurrence (where new users even attempt to format code).

Can the display formatting be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Also happens with the Android app, though nobody's going to fix that.